# После сборки webpack'om файл index.html открывается в браузере пустой

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Такое ощущение, как будто не подцепляется файл со скриптом, хотя он прописан. При запуске webpack dev server всё работает. Мб для окончательной сборки нужно тоже, чтобы был какой-то сервер?

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000,
        watchContentBase: true,
        progress: true
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [{
                            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>testTask, bro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">

    </div>
<script src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

main.js и index.html лежат в одной папке.

Answer (score 0):

Да, так и есть. Вам необходимо установить `http-server` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)).
Установить его можно глобально, хотя и локально тоже подойдет.

При локальной установке запустите команду `$ npm run http-server` в папке с `index.html`
При глобальной, просто `$ http-server`

По идее, после запуска, он должен будет написать что-то вроде этого:

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./ through http
Available on:
  https:127.0.0.1:8080
  https:192.168.1.101:8080
  https:192.168.1.104:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

Переходите по `localhost:8080` и будет вам счастье. :)

Comment: Скорее всего мимо. У него `devServer` в конфиге - вероятно, речь в вопросе о запуске через него.

Comment: @Qwertiy, наоборот же написано, что через devServer работает. Я лично предполагаю, что он открывает index.html и браузер .js файл не может найти. Ну, если мимо - подкорректирую, есть все же недостаток информации.

Comment: @NocteFury сделал всё, как вы написали, установил локально. В папке с index.html запустил сервер, он в терминале написал пару адресов, которые в браузере можно открыть. Но если переходить по ним или localhost:8080, то отображается структура моего проекта. А если я открываю файл index.html, то он всё равно в браузере пустой.

Comment: @Areestokrat, попробуйте добавить в output, поле publicPath. И укажите в него '/'

Answer (score 0):

На зарубежном stackoverflow нашёл ответ. Если используется react-router-dom, то нужно импортировать не BrowserRouter, а HashRouter.
Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550560/why-is-react-webpack-production-build-showing-blank-page) подробно описано.

Comment: Либо BrowserRouter можно оставить, а в webpack.config.js дописать: в devServer: { historyApiFallback: true }, в output:{ publicPath: '/',}